# Pre-calculus: Rule for fractional exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I go on about evaluating $(a^4)^3$ when $a = ({2\over 3})^{1\over 6}$ ?

I tried simplifying with my calculator, but I didn't know the 'method' for dealing with these. I still got it wrong in the end.

Regards,

Comment: Recall rule of exponents before you substitute.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $(x^y)^z = x^{yz}$, so $(a^4)^3=a^{12}$.  Now use the same trick after plugging the value of $a$ into $a^{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{extpfeil}\Newextarrow{\xRightarrow}{5,5}{0x21D2}$
$$(a^4)^3=a^{12}\xRightarrow[\text{the value of $a$}]{\text{plugging in}} \left(\left({2\over 3}\right)^{1/6}\right)^{12}=\left({2\over 3}\right)^{\frac16\times12}=\left({2\over 3}\right)^{2}=\dfrac{2^2}{3^2}=\dfrac49$$

Comment: Maybe the use of brackets rather than curley braces would keep the notation unambiguous to the OP. Otherwise +1 :)

Comment: @Alizter You're right, edited. Thanks! ;-)